# Rename-item in multiple subfolders

Tags: powershell, rename

I have a piece of software which looks for a files named "report.txt". However, the text files aren't all named report.txt and I have hundreds of sub folders to go through.

Scenario:

```
J:\Logs
26-09-16\log.txt
27-09-16\report270916.txt
28-09-16\report902916.txt
```

I want to search through all the sub folders for the files `*.txt` in `J:\logs` and rename them to `report.txt`.

I tried this but it complained about the path:

```
Get-ChildItem * |
Where-Object { !$_.PSIsContainer } |
Rename-Item -NewName { $_.name -replace '_$.txt ','report.txt' }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Get-ChildItem *` will get your current path, so in instead let's use the define the path you want `Get-ChildItem -Path "J:\Logs"` and add `recurse` because we want the files in all the subfolders.

Then let's add use the `include` and `file` parameter of `Get-ChildItem` rather than `Where-Object`

Then if we pipe that to `ForEach`, we can use the Rename-Item on each object, where the object to rename will be `$_` and the `NewName` will be `report.txt`.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "J:\Logs" -include "*.txt" -file -recurse | ForEach {Rename-Item -Path $_ -NewName "report.txt"}
```

We can trim this down a bit in one-liner fashion with a couple aliases and rely on position rather than listing each parameter

```
gci "J:\Logs" -include "*.txt" -file -recurse | % {ren $_ "report.txt"}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what i wanted. :)

Answer (score 0):

To replace certin word in all files in all sub folders

```
Get-ChildItem C:\Path -Recurse -Filter *OldWord* | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.name -replace 'OldWord', 'NewWord'} -verbose
```